# PoEdit, warning: internationalized messages should not contain the '\r' escape sequence

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, poedit

I am using wordpress with buddyboss as theme. And I want to have other text messages on the registration form. So I follow this tutorial:

```
https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/customizing/customizing-labels-messages-and-urls/
```

But at the moment I choose for Create new translation. I get this error:

```
28/01/2022 17:37:15: C:\Users\SAVANT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\poeA4A8.tmp\ref.pot:7544: warning: internationalized messages should not contain the '\r' escape sequence
```

But when I try to go to that address:

```
C:\Users\SAVANT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\poeA4A8.tmp\ref.pot:7544:
```

I even don't see a file with name

```
poeA4A8.tmp
```

And yes, I triggered the option show hidden files.

So my question is:

How   to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

\r "Carriage Return" should not be contained in the string you want to translate.

```
message += gettext('Message is invalid\r\n')
```

the correct way is:

```
message += gettext('Email is invalid') + '\r\n'
```